# I can't load curl.so and I get an: undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use [`curl_init()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) but I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

So, I activated the `curl.so` extension but when I restart apache I get the following errorlog:

```
[16-Mar-2016 09:18:48 Europe/Zurich] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so, 9):
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 in Unknown on line 0
[16-Mar-2016 09:18:48 Europe/Zurich] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so, 9):
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: oauth.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 in Unknown on line 0
[16-Mar-2016 09:18:48 Europe/Zurich] PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'solr' because required module 'curl' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I've updated `curl` and `libcurl.4.dylib` and when I inspect this library with:

`$ otool -L /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`

I get the following trace:

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1153.18.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57031.20.26)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

As you can see it say that I've the `libcurl.4.dylib` with `(compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)`, so I don't understand the error I got of the errorlog from apache.

The same happens if I inspect `curl`, where I get the following trace:

```
$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
$ otool -L /usr/bin/curl
/usr/bin/curl:
    /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.42.1/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57031.20.26)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1153.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Any thoughts of what the error can be or how can I get `curl_init()` to work?

I'm using:

- OSX Yosemite: 10.10.3
- Apache: 2.4.10
- curl: 7.42.1
- PHP: 5.3.29

Comment: uncomment the line
`;extension=php_curl.dll`
in php.ini, and then restart the Apache service.

Comment: Since you're using XAMPP, file path in `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`

Comment: @AmbalMani I'm using OSX so i edited the `php.ini`file with `extension=curl.so` then there is when I get the first errorlog. Also I'm not using XAMPP.

Comment: @rog3r It looks like its trying to install an out of date version of curl. Try manually installing an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to update curl and recompile php_curl.so from the PHP souce.